# How add dot following the chapter number on the content and on the table of contents in report class

Tags: table-of-contents, report

Dear last time a received message really quickly. I checked some of solution found here and in the internet, but those don't working for me. I'm placing MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, outer=15mm, inner=35mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titleformat
{\part} 
[display]
{\bfseries \huge \itshape\centering} 
{Część \ \thepart} 
{0.5ex} 
{
    \rule{\textwidth}{0pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \centering
} 
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}
] 

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\thechapter}{18pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\rfoot{Strona ~\thepage~} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\chapter
{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
{\par}% Inserting a \par here!
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{The Part name}
    ...
    \chapter{The First Chapter name}
    ...
    \chapter{The Second Chapter name}
    ...
    \chapter{The Third Chapter name}
    ...

\end{document}
```

I would like to have the dot after chapter number in table of contents and the content as well. Could someone help me in this matter?

Comment: Does adding `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}` to the premble of your document result in the desired output?

Comment: @leandriis: this will result in adding a dot to every reference to the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `titlesec` and its companion packages `titleps` and `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[vmargin=25mm, outer=15mm, inner=35mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[newparttoc, clearempty, explicit, newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat
{\part}
[display]
{\bfseries \huge \itshape\filcenter}
{Część \ \thepart}
{3.5ex}
{#1 }

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\thispagestyle{empty}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\thechapter.}{18pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}

\newpagestyle{myplain}{%
\sethead{}{}{}
\setfoot[~Strona ~\thepage][][]{}{}{Strona ~\thepage~}
}

\pagestyle{myplain}

    \titlecontents{chapter}
    [0em] %
    {\bigskip\bfseries\large}
    {\thecontentslabel.\enspace}%\thecontentslabel
    {}
    {\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \part{The Part name}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \chapter{The First Chapter name}
    \lipsum[4-12]
    \chapter{The Second Chapter name}
    \lipsum[13-24]
    \chapter{The Third Chapter name}
    \lipsum[25-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. But your code changing my whole document. I fugured out after your answer what I have to change, but for those who don't know the better would be answer pointing what has to be changed. Thanks!

Comment: @EmilKob: What has to be changed, except `fancyhdr` and `titleps` are not compatible, since they tackle the same parameters?

Comment: I'm not a specialist in Tex settings. I even can't answer your questions. I know that Tex allows to set appearance as user wants but I'm regular user which will need sometimes help. Thank you for your post because it's enable me to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After the answer given by Bernard I would like to clarify what has to be done to make the changes described in my question. I add a comments at the side of things which has to be added.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, outer=15mm, inner=35mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titleformat
{\part} 
[display]
{\bfseries \huge \itshape\centering} 
{Część \ \thepart} 
{0.5ex} 
{
    \rule{\textwidth}{0pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \centering
} 
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}
] 

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\thechapter.}{18pt}{\huge} %%--you had to add dot at the end of thechapter word
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\rfoot{Strona ~\thepage~} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\chapter
{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
{\par}
{}{}
\makeatother

%%--you have to put this phrase which formatting the table of content appearance
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0em] 
{\bigskip\bfseries\large}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace}%\thecontentslabel
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{The Part name}
    ...
    \chapter{The First Chapter name}
    ...
    \chapter{The Second Chapter name}
    ...
    \chapter{The Third Chapter name}
    ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not understand what the rules with 0pt thickness are for?

Comment: Hi, me as well :)

Comment: I've just found out I forgot to post the simplified code (without the rules with 0 thickness, which seemed to be there only for problems of vertical spacing). I've just updated.